# Accidentally Application Server removed from the SharePoint 2010 Farm

Tags: central-administration

I have one serious issue if any one can guide.
My SharePoint 2010 server is working with 3-tire concept like WFE1, WFE2, APPSP1, APPSP2 & NLB with CLUDB.

Accidentally I found some issue & when i diagnostic that i found that App1 Server is not working. In the Central Admin > Servers in Farm I found App1 Not Configured State.

Error Screen:

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=38afb947eee6ed1d&id=38AFB947EEE6ED1D%211381&sff=1#cid=38AFB947EEE6ED1D&id=38AFB947EEE6ED1D%211382

the I clicked on that App Server & found couple of services are in Stopping mode (not started, not stopped)

Here is the screen of that:

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=38afb947eee6ed1d&id=38AFB947EEE6ED1D%211381&sff=1#cid=38AFB947EEE6ED1D&id=38AFB947EEE6ED1D%211381

Now, Can anyone guide me how we can resume this at normal stage & also what would be the possible cause of this ?

Comment: I would start by running Config Wizard (rebooting if necessary to 'stop' those services), either removing the server from the farm if it detects that it is joined, or if it doesn't detect that it is joined, removing the server from Manage servers in farm.  Once that is complete, simply re-run Config Wizard and join the farm.